# MPMoviePlayerViewController setCurrentPlaybackTime goes to the wrong position

Tags: iphone, ios, video, mpmovieplayer

I have an application where I play a video in the background, the process is very simple, the same behavior is repeated endlessly. On a user gesture the movie is played for a couple of seconds and paused, The application works perfectly as long as the suer didn't press the home button. when the application comes from the back-ground to the front-ground the video turns all black till the user makes a gesture.

In order to resolve the black screen problem, I shared the player object, then in AppDelegate.m < applicationDidBecomeActive > I prepare the player using the function

```
[sharedObj.player.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
```

then I move its position to where is should be (because the player is returned to the starting point of the video at this time), to do so I call this function

```
[sharedObj.player.moviePlayer setCurrentPlaybackTime: whereItShouldBe];
```

And here comes my problem, the video isn't placed where it should be. there is a big difference between the "whereItShouldBe" time and "wherItIsCurrently".

I verified that it's the same object using the object identifier, so did anybody already faced a similar issue ? or has an idea to support me. Thanks in advance.

---

### UPDATE

**Closed**: closed as not resolved see the comments bellow the question

Comment: can you specify better what is "there is a big difference" for you ? Seconds, minutes ? Earlier, later ?

Comment: Ok, I will put a numeric example: when ever I want to set the playback time to 1.2 (seconds) than it is set to 0.94 (seconds) and this is not a fixed difference, some times its bigger

Comment: this difference (up to 0.5 seconds) is quite normal, depending on codec and framerate it may vary. You can skip ONLY to some keyframe, which may vary. 
So, for example, for h264 25fps that would mean 0.2-0.3s between keyframes.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but isn't there any way or work around to get the expected result ? May be another video format (currently I'm using mpg4). Thanks in advance

Comment: if you can edit the video file, use something like VirtualDub to insert more keyframes and check the result