# MPMoviePlayerViewController shows wrong time

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am playing a video using MPMoviePlayerViewController Now the problem is that it shows 0.00 sec in progress bar even after 1 sec. After then it start working fine. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: according to the comments in this SO question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136420/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-setcurrentplaybacktime-goes-to-the-wrong-position, it seems it is normal for that discrepancy.

Comment: I think you may want to read this SO question as well about MPMoviePlayerViewController, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364147/why-does-mpmovieplayercontroller-setcurrentplaybacktime-goes-to-the-wrong-time

Answer (score 0):

You can set seek time for the MPMoviePlayerViewController

[Player seekToTime:CMTimeMake(9,1)];

Comment: Can you please specify how it should be used and MPMoviePlayerViewController has no property like seekToTime:CMTimeMake

Comment: @user1487846 Sorry i forgot to tell you that property is available in AVPlayer, you need to switch from MPMoviePlayerViewController to AVPLayer